# How can I solve the probability question regarding the percentages of covid patients?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, percentages

The probability of someone getting COVID-19 in Thailand when they have been given the COVID-19 vaccine is 0.1. Without the vaccine, the probability of getting COVID-19 is 0.4. If 30% of the population has been given the vaccine, what is the probability that a person chosen at random from the population will get COVID-19 in Thailand? (Round to nearest hundredth.)

My attempt:

(0.3)*(0.1) + (0.7)*(0.4) = 31 percent...

I think I'm doing this wrongly here. If I am wrong, what changes should I make?

Comment: Your work is correct, good job. What were you doubtful about?

Comment: so this is right?